# How to get console output of downstream job in upstream job?

Tags: powershell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm trying to find a workaround because first question still is unanswered.
[can't run Start-Job with credentials from Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397232/cant-run-start-job-with-credentials-from-jenkins)

I have job A. Job A starts powershell script at server and shows some output.

Also I have a pipeline B that runs multiple copy of job A against different servers. 
Here is the groovy code

```
stage 'Copy sources from Git'
build job: 'DeploymentJobs/1_CopySourcesFromGit'
stage 'Deploy to servers'
def servers = env.SERVERLIST.split('\n')
def steps =[:]

for (int i=0; i<servers.size(); i++) {
    def server = servers[i]
    def stepName = "running ${server}"
    steps[stepName] = {->
        echo server
        build job: 'DeploymentJobs/2_DeployToServer', parameters: 
[booleanParam(name: 'REBOOTAFTER', value: Boolean.valueOf(REBOOTAFTER)), 
string(name: 'SERVERNAME', value: server)]
    }

}

parallel steps
```

In the output of pipeline I see only info than N copies of job A started but no their output.
I want to see only powershell output from all instances of job A in console output of pipeline B.

I have no iedea how to do this, Is it possible.

Answer (score 4):

A shorter alternative:

```
def result = build job: 'job_name', wait: true
println result.getRawBuild().getLog()
```

It will be necessary to whitelist both methods.

Edit: since you don't want to wait for the build to run, you could add this at the end of your job (or at some point after all triggered builds should be finished) where number_of_builds in your case will be servers.size().

```
def job = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName('job_A_name')
def last_build = job.getLastBuild().getNumber()
def first_build = last_build - number_of_builds

(first_build..last_build).each {
    println "Log of build $it"
    def build = job.getBuildByNumber(it)
    println build.log
}
```

If you really want to be sure the builds you're getting are the ones triggered by your job, you can get the build cause from the build object.

Comment: Should it work with wait: false. Cause it doesn't in my case. I want stage to continue if one of jobs fail. But when I put "wait: false" into code, pipeline throws exception "Also:   java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getRawBuild() on null object
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getRawBuild() on null object"

Comment: @PaWeLL
No, it won't work. By the time you try to get the results the other build probably hasn't even started. The fact that you want the results of the triggered job but don't want to wait for it or stop the flow in case it fails makes this a lot more complicated. I'll edit the response.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/51408261/3364871 with update of `getLog()` to `getLog(int)` since 2007-11-11 to avoid loading the whole log into memory unnecessarily.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem by adding this into the cycle. I could get log of downstrema jobs into upstream, display it and work with it.

```
def checkjob = build job: 'job name', parameters: [ any params here]
checklog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName('job name').getBuildByNumber(checkjob.getNumber()).log
println checklog
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a silly example:

```
$myJobs = @()
$myJobs += Start-job -ScriptBlock { while (1) {Get-Item 'c:\*'; sleep 5}}
$myJobs += Start-job -ScriptBlock { while (1) {Get-Item 'c:\windows\*'; sleep 5}}

try {
    while(1)
    {
        $myJobs | Get-Job -HasMoreData $true | Receive-Job
    }
} finally {
    $myJobs | Stop-Job
    $myJobs | Remove-Job
}
```

Anything the job pipelines is queued. The `-HasMoreData` state indicates that the job has output that is available to read. The parent receives the output using `Receive-Job`. By default it displays in the console, but you can receive the output in the parent process and do further processing.

If this isn't what you're going for you'll have to be more specific in your question. Provide a little of the code you've tried so far.

Comment: I have added groovy code in question. May be this will explain what I want to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, I assumed this was PowerShell-related; I don't know groovy. Does this groovy code call a posh script at some point? If not, you may want to remove the powershell tag.

Comment: Yes groovy calls powershell script. This question is related to powershell but powershell is not main point.

Answer (score 0):

```
def jobLog = Jenkins.getInstance().getItemByFullName('job-path/testjob').getLastSuccessfulBuild().log
println(jobLog)
```