# How to get rolling console output from downstream Jenkins job in upstream job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have an upstream job which is invoking a long-running downstream job. I'd like to monitor the rolling console output of the downstream job in the upstream log output.

[image: Currently it just shows this in upstream log]

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: You may find answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48460437/how-to-get-console-output-of-downstream-job-in-upstream-job/48567461

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I think this is for only after the downstream build completes running. In my case, I'm wanting it to show rolling logs while its running